# AsynTask doInBackground error

Tags: android, json

I am trying to post an item into a database but I am facing a fatal exception with AsynTask. Been trying to find a solution for quite a while but still am not able to fix it. I have added the internet permission in the manifest already.

Here is the logcat:

```
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.PostItemForm$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(PostItemForm.java:103)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.PostItemForm$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(PostItemForm.java:1)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-23 10:38:24.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2202):     ... 4 more
02-23 10:38:24.866: I/Choreographer(2202): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 10:38:25.616: I/Choreographer(2202): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202): Activity my.fyp.inticlassifieds.PostItemForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b12d87c8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity my.fyp.inticlassifieds.PostItemForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b12d87c8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.PostItemForm$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(PostItemForm.java:92)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.PostItemForm$1.onClick(PostItemForm.java:72)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 10:38:27.246: E/WindowManager(2202):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class PostItemForm extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText itemName;
    EditText itemPrice;
    EditText itemDesc;
    Spinner itemCat;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://inticlassifields.comze.com/public_html/phpscripts/post_item.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_item_form);

        // Edit Text
        itemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.i_itemname);
        itemPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.i_price);
        itemDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.i_des);

        itemCat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.item_cat, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        itemCat.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitpostitem);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PostItemForm.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Posting item..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String date_posted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
            String name = itemName.getText().toString();
            String price = itemPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = itemDesc.getText().toString();
            String category = itemCat.getSelectedItem().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date_posted));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Toast.makeText(PostItemForm.this,"Item posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
    }
```

I fixed the nullpointerexception but now I am facing another problem with my json. what type of error is this?

`02-24 03:07:36.478: E/JSON(2309): <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
02-24 03:07:36.478: E/JSON(2309): <b>Warning</b>:  require_once(include/DB_Functions.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/a3335925/public_html/phpscripts/index.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
02-24 03:07:36.478: E/JSON(2309): <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table><br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
02-24 03:07:36.478: E/JSON(2309): <b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'include/DB_Functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/a3335925/public_html/phpscripts/index.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
02-24 03:07:36.478: E/JSON(2309): <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>
02-24 03:07:36.478: E/JSON Parser(2309): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: You have a null pointer on line 103 - which line of code is line 103? I'm guessing your Log.d("Create Response...

Comment: @BenPearson 103 is String category = itemCat.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Are you sure that you initilized the right Spinner that the layout contains?

Comment: plz make sure itemCat.getSelectedItem() is not null. I think it's null in your case.

Comment: http://p.pw/404 - Are you getting a 404 (page not found) error?

Comment: @AtulOHolic found that that 404 was due to my link. now i am having another problem with it.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your Spinner twice which is the reason Null Pointer Error is throwing up.

If you see, at class level you have,

```
  Spinner itemCat;
```

and then in your onCreate you again have,

```
 Spinner itemCat = //your layout Spinner.
```

Hence, you have initialized your local Spinner variable itemCat and in asynctask you are calling the class level itemCat which is still null.

In the onCreate simply change,

```
 Spinner itemCat = //your layout Spinner.
```

to

```
itemCat = //your layout Spinner.
```

Comment: +1 well spotted, I missed that when I posted my answer

Comment: now i have another nullpointerexception at `Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());`

Comment: Change this Log.d("Create Response", json.toString()); to Log.d("Create Response", String.valueOf(json)); and you will notice that it prints null, which means your json is null. Please check this and let know.

Comment: @AtulOHolic json is null hence `NullPointerException`

Comment: @firaga your json is null. make sure you get the json from the server and its not null

Comment: Yes @Raghunandan. I meant the same. I asked to do this, so that it gets visible to firaga as well. firaga - as Raghunandan said, please ensure you get the json data and put a null check so that in case json is null again you get a message and you will know it.

Comment: why is my json retrieving html?
`02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON(2338):         <script type="text/javascript">
02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON(2338):             <!--
02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON(2338):             window.location = "http://p.pw/404"
02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON(2338):             //-->
02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON(2338):         </script>
02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON(2338):     
02-23 11:15:57.730: E/JSON Parser(2338): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Answer (score 1):

You can only make UI changes from the UI thread. You are creating a toast from within `doInBackground` which runs in another thread. You need to create your toast on your `onPostExecute` method or in the `onProgressUpdated` method.

So, in your case, you should make your `doInBackground` method return the value of success which will be caught in your onPostExceute(). There you can check if value of success is 1 everything was ok and 0 if not, and then on `onPostExecute` method see what value was returned and act consequently.

Comment: but this does not `NullPointerException`

Comment: which line is 103? Anyway, NullPointer or not, you will be having this problem sooner or later

Comment: Your spinner is returning that nothing is selected. Try null-safing that line by checking if there's a selection first.